# Local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def main():
        tests = get_initial_input(tests)
        assignments = get_initial_input(assignments)
        exercises = get_initial_input(exercises)
        labs = get_initial_input(labs)
        finals = get_initial_input(finals)
        print(tests, assignments, labs)


def get_initial_input(x):
        val = int(input("How many", x , "were there?    "))
        return val

main()
```

I keep getting an error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tests' referenced before assignment
```

I've tried many different things to try to get tests to go to `get_initial_input()` but it says that it is referenced before assignment.

How is that possible when the first line of code I'm trying to define it?

Comment: Yes, but `tests` doesn't exist when you call `get_initial_input(tests)`. What do you expect it to print?

Comment: You never define the variable `tests` until after the line `tests=get_initial_answer(tests)`, so `tests` is undefined during the execution of that line.

Comment: Also, just as a side note, I think by `get_initial_input(tests)`, you meant `get_initial_input("tests")`, and `val = int(input("How many", x , "were there?    "))` as `val = int(input("How many" + x + "were there?    "))` Revised working code: https://repl.it/B0Ex

Comment: Thanks Patrick I was forgetting the quotes, that's what I needed. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to pass a *string* to your function, which is used in the input prompt. A literal string is always surrounded by quotes.

```
tests = get_initial_input("tests")
```

This would be easier to debug if you'd used a proper variable name - eg `label` - in your function argument.

Answer (score 8):

When you use:

```
tests = get_initial_input(tests)
```

the first thing that happens is that Python tries to evaluate this:

```
get_initial_input(tests)
```

But `tests` is not defined yet, so you get an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: But that's how I want to define tests.  And I've done something so similar to this and I can't figure out why it won't work.

Comment: Sorry, but Python does not support recursive variable definitions on the form of `x = x`. You need to define it to be something. Perhaps you want to use a string value instead of a variable name?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing unassigned variable `tests` to `get_initial_input()` function. So, that's why you receive the error.

If you need a default value inside `get_initial_input()` function for x argument, then define it explicitly:

```
def get_initial_input(x=5):
    ...
```

And in `main()` call it for `tests` variable without arguments:

```
tests = get_initial_input()
```

If you need names (e.g. `'How many tests'`) - then pass strings, not cars to the function:

```
tests = get_initial_input('tests')
```